# Yolo issue with detecting positives

Tags: tensorflow, computer-vision, object-detection, yolo, implementation

I've recently tried to implement a Yolo detector for traffic light detection based on yolo v1 implementation in Tensorflow/Keras.  My model really struggles with detecting small objects. Loss function components drop on training, but all this does is seemingly push confidence values to really small values (Since there are many more cells that do not contain objects, one way model could minimize loss function would be to push all confidences to 0).

It usually detects objects where traffic lights appear in dataset, so in some way it is learning a distribution of correct positions/size ratios, but it fails to predict correct bounding boxes on some concrete example from training set, like in the following image:

[image]

I've used the net proposed in the original paper with 448 x 448 resolution images, however without pretraining. I've actually tried using VGG-16 net pretrained on Imagenet as a feature extractor and adding some convolutional and FC layers, but with similar results :(-

My loss function chooses a predictor for each object in a grid cell base on highest IoU with that object.
It adds a squared difference from that predictor multiplied by 0.1 factor if there was no object there. If there was an object that predictor was assigned to, it only adds the squared difference loss. Also a predictor can be assigned to multiple objects (as per [this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/85306/yolov1-algorithm-how-to-determine-predictor-responsibility/87370?noredirect=1#comment93075_87370) answer).

So I'm at a loss here (pun intended) and have a few questions.

a) Is pretraining really necessary, and if, can I use a net that was pretrained as classifier on a different dataset, and different objects (other than traffic lights) as a feature extractor.

b) Could I improve performance by running the net on negative examples first (images with no traffic lights), then adding positive examples?

I used the Bosch Small Traffic Light Dataset. Here is my entire loss function:

```
class YoloLoss():

  def __init__(self, step=0):
    self.step = step
    

  def call(self, y_true, y_preds):
    """
    Args:
        ground_truth: np.array [batch_size, s, s , b, (4 + 1)]
        y_preds: tf.Tensor [batch_size, ss, b, (4 + 1)] 

    Returns:
        loss for each element of batch 
    """
    batch,s,s,b,_ = y_true.shape
    ss = s * s 
    size1 = [batch, ss, b, 5]
   
    cy = tf.tile(tf.range(s, dtype=tf.float32)[...,None], [1, s])
    cx = tf.tile(tf.range(s, dtype=tf.float32)[None,...], [s, 1])
    
    cell_xy = tf.reshape(tf.stack([cx,cy], axis=-1), [1, ss, 1, 2])  # [1, ss, 1, 2]
    cell_xy = tf.tile(cell_xy, [batch, 1, b, 1]) # [batch, ss, b, 2]

    # ==== PREDICTIONS ====
    #y_preds = tf.reshape(y_preds, size1) # [batch, SS, B, 5]

    # Transform net outputs
    net_confs = y_preds[..., 4] # [batch, SS, B, 2]
    net_xy = y_preds[..., 0:2] # [batch, SS, B, 2]
    net_wh = tf.exp(y_preds[..., 2:4]) # [batch, SS, B, 2]

    """
    net_confs = tf.sigmoid(y_preds[..., 4]) # [batch, SS, B, 2]
    net_xy = tf.sigmoid(y_preds[..., 0:2]) # [batch, SS, B, 2]
    net_wh = tf.exp(y_preds[..., 2:4]) # [batch, SS, B, 2]
    """
    
    pred_confs = tf.expand_dims(net_confs, axis=2) #[batch, SS, 1, B]
    pred_wh = tf.expand_dims(net_wh, axis=2) # [batch, SS, 1, B, 2]
    pred_centers = tf.expand_dims(net_xy + cell_xy, axis=2)  # [batch, ss, 1, b, 2]
    pred_floor = pred_centers - (0.5 * pred_wh)  # [batch, SS, 1, B, 2]
    pred_ceil  = pred_centers + (0.5 * pred_wh)  # [batch, SS, 1, B, 2]
    pred_area = pred_wh[..., 0] * pred_wh[..., 1] # [batch, SS, 1, B]

    
    # ==== GROUND TRUTH ==== 
    y_true = tf.reshape(y_true, size1)

    p_obj = tf.expand_dims(y_true[..., 4], axis=3) #[batch, ss, B, 1]
    true_floor = tf.expand_dims(y_true[..., 0:2], axis=3)  # [batch, ss, B, 1, 2]
    true_ceil  = tf.expand_dims(y_true[..., 2:4], axis=3)  # [batch, ss, B, 1, 2]
    true_wh = true_ceil - true_floor # [batch, ss, B, 1, 2]
    true_area = true_wh[..., 0] * true_wh[..., 1] # [batch, ss, B, 1]
    true_centers = 0.5 * (true_floor + true_ceil) # [batch, ss, B, 1, 2] 


    # ==== CALCULATE IOU (TRUTH, PREDS) ==== 

    xy_floor = tf.math.maximum(true_floor, pred_floor) # [batch, ss, B, B, 2]
    xy_ceil  = tf.math.minimum(true_ceil, pred_ceil) # [batch, ss, B, B, 2]
    
    z = tf.math.maximum(0.0, xy_ceil - xy_floor) #[batch, ss, B, B, 2]
    inter_area = z[..., 0] * z[..., 1] #[batch, ss, B, B]

    union_area = true_area + pred_area - inter_area # [batch, ss, B, B]

    iou = tf.math.truediv(inter_area, union_area) # [batch, ss, b, b]


    # ==== PREDICTOR RESPONSIBILITY ==== 

    # iou_mask[:,:,i,j] = 1.0 if object predictor j is assigned to object i
    responsibility_mask = tf.cast(tf.equal(tf.argsort(tf.argsort(iou, 3, direction='DESCENDING'), 3), 0), tf.float32) # [batch, ss, b, b]
    cobj = responsibility_mask * p_obj   # [batch, ss, b, b]
    cnoobj = responsibility_mask * (1. - p_obj) # [batch, ss, b, b]
    
    # ==== LOSS COMPONENTS ==== 
    scoord = tf.constant(5.0, dtype=tf.float32)
    snoobj = tf.constant(0.1, dtype=tf.float32)
    sconf  = tf.constant(5.0, dtype=tf.float32)

    xy_diff = tf.math.square(pred_centers - true_centers) * cobj[..., None] # [batch, ss, b, b, 2]
    xy_loss = tf.math.reduce_sum(xy_diff, axis=[1,2,3,4]) # [batch]

    wh_diff = tf.math.square(tf.sqrt(pred_wh) - tf.sqrt(true_wh)) * cobj[..., None] # [batch, ss, b, b, 2]
    wh_loss = tf.math.reduce_sum(wh_diff, axis=[1,2,3,4]) # [batch]

    iou_diff = tf.math.square(pred_confs - iou) # [batch, ss, b, b]

    conf_diff = iou_diff * cobj # [batch, ss, b, b]
    conf_loss = tf.math.reduce_sum(conf_diff, axis=[1,2,3])

    noobj_diff = iou_diff * cnoobj #[batch, ss, b, b]
    noobj_loss = tf.math.reduce_sum(noobj_diff, axis=[1,2,3])

   
    loss = scoord * (xy_loss + wh_loss) + sconf * conf_loss + snoobj * noobj_loss 
    loss = tf.math.reduce_sum(loss)

    tf.summary.scalar("xy_loss", tf.math.reduce_mean(xy_loss), step=self.step)
    tf.summary.scalar("wh_loss", tf.math.reduce_mean(wh_loss), step=self.step)
    tf.summary.scalar("conf_loss", tf.math.reduce_mean(conf_loss), step=self.step)
    tf.summary.scalar("noobj_loss", tf.math.reduce_mean(noobj_loss), step=self.step)

    self.step += 1

    return loss
```

Comment: Not a answer for your question, but can you try YoloV3, this is specifially designed to identify smaller object where yolov1 is failing.

Comment: @SaandeepSreerambatla I know of YoloV3, but I'm kinda stuck with Yolov1 since I don't have enough time to re-implement the thing for yolov3

Comment: YOLOv3 uses a higher resolution grids (13x13, 26x26 and 52x52, instead of 7x7) to detect smaller objects. Given this, it may be wortwhile to increase the resolution of the grid you are using. On the other hand, if one problem that you have detected is that the loss pushes confidence values to really small values, then it may help to decrease more the constant $\lambda_{\text{noobj}}$ that weights the confidence error of the grid cells without objects.